# Set up a Virtual Host for Apache in CentOS

Tags: apache, centos, virtualhost

Is it possible to set up a Virtual Host for Apache in CentOS somewhere outside /var/www? (say /home/myuser/mywebsite)

I tried different alternatives but none worked.

This is the entry i added in my vhost file for testing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testfer
    DocumentRoot /home/builder/testfer

    <Directory "/home/builder/testfer">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You can enable FollowSymlinks. Then create symlink to /var/www folder

Comment: I tried but i get 403 (Forbidden) if i do that. I also tried setting perms 755 for directories and 644 for files (with chmod) but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you should update your vhost file here :)

Comment: @BQKhánh i just added the vhost definition